# Equal Topnavigation on different Sitecollections?

Tags: 2010, navigation, site-collection

I have several Sitecollections and all of them should have the exact same Topnavigationbar. Publishing Feature is activated. 
**Example**:
On Sitecollection A the Topnavigation should show 
*Sitecollection A* | sitecollection B | sitecollection C 
On Sitecollection  B the Topnavigation should show 
Sitecollection A | *sitecollection B* | sitecollection C 
And so on...

Any ideas how to get this done? Could i do this via powershell? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box it's not possible. Take a look at a custom sitemap provider to dynamically retrieve sitecollection data; The data can be retrieved from an XML file (XmlContentMapProvider), SharePoint list or even directly via the object model.

For more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc789625.aspx

There are also third party tools on the market to achieve this.

Comment: Hey Sven, thanks for your response. I will try it...